# PHP to convert <img> tag to custom XML

Tags: php, html, xml

I'm teaching myself PHP for a small project. I need to convert all of the  tags in a source HTML file (there may be many) into custom XML. I've been trying out things with the DOMDocument class, but can't seem to get stuff to work right.

As an example, I need to convert

```
<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-23904" src="https://picnic.ly/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Screen-Shot-2560-01-27-at-2.32.06-PM-1024x572.png" alt="this is a picture" width="1024" height="574" />
```

To

```
<image>
<description>VALUE FROM ALT</description>
<url>VALUE FROM SRC</url>
</image>
```

Would love some help on this ... thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your attempt please.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to get XML string:

```
<?php
// We use dom document to load it as an php object
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML('<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-23904" src="https://picnic.ly/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Screen-Shot-2560-01-27-at-2.32.06-PM-1024x572.png" alt="this is a picture" width="1024" height="574" />');
$img = $document->getElementsByTagName("img")->item(0);
// The Wrapper for your xml
$xml = "<image>\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < $img->attributes->length; $i++) {
    $attribute = $img->attributes->item($i);
    $name = $attribute->name;
    $value = $attribute->textContent;
    // Indent the element
    $xml .= "    ";
    // Create the element
    $xml .= "<" . $name . ">";
    $xml .= $value;
    $xml .= "</" . $name . ">";
    // Break line at end
    $xml .= "\n";
}
$xml .= "</image>";
echo $xml;
```

and the result:

```
<image>
    <class>alignnone size-large wp-image-23904</class>
    <src>https://picnic.ly/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Screen-Shot-2560-01-27-at-2.32.06-PM-1024x572.png</src>
    <alt>this is a picture</alt>
    <width>1024</width>
    <height>574</height>
</image>
```

Tell me if this is not your want solution or has problem.

**EDIT**: Best Solution is http://syframework.alwaysdata.net/44j i have created.

Comment: Hi ... Thanks a lot for that. It was a good start for me, I modified the code so that it 1. loops over all images and 2. replaces the original <img src...> tag with the XML. The looping over all images works, BUT for some reason when I try to replace the <img> tag with the <image> XML, I'm getting some odd problems. Any ideas? Thanks!


The code is a bit too long to post here, so I put it at this link http://syframework.alwaysdata.net/41r

Comment: Hi. forgive me for late. go [http://syframework.alwaysdata.net/44j](http://syframework.alwaysdata.net/44j) for best solution. it is faster and better than old.

Comment: Hi! Tell me your problem is fixed.

Answer (score -1):

```
<image>
  <src>the url to the image</src>
  <alt>alt_Description_</alt>
  <description>Add_Image_description</description>
  <class>Image_Class_Add_</class>
  <height>Image_height_in_pixels</height>
  <width>Image_width_in_pixels</width>
  <title>Whatever_title_you_want_for_the_image</title>
</image>
```