# Parsing HTML to XML

Tags: php, html, xml, validation, parsing

I'm working with text/HTML diffing engine that's using XML in it's core but we're inputting HTML5 data, I wonder how to take care of tags that don't need to be closed in HTML5, but must be closed in XML. For Example:

`<img alt="" height="239" src="http://example.com/image.png" width="272">`

Do I need to convert every tag manually (Just like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919169/php-to-convert-img-tag-to-custom-xml/41919346))?

Is there a tool that would do this for me? And save a headache escaping all self-closing HTML tags?

For example `xml_parse()` runs following code like it has an error, but `body` has a valid HTML which is invalid XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html [<!ENTITY Aacute "&#193;">]>
<body>
    <div>
        <figure class="table ">
            <figcaption>
                <p class="table_number"></p>
                <p class="table_title" epub:type="title"></p>
            </figcaption>
            <table class="code ">
                <tr>
                    <td width="50">
                        <img alt="" height="239" src="http://example.com/image.png" width="272">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </figure>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: They should be closed in HTML, just because the "modern" browser is smart enough to close them doesn't mean it's cool to leave them un-closed.  That's my Opinion.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, thanks for the comment but this is not possible in my case. Our data is already in database and cannot be updated. There's a whole bit of a legacy html junk.

Comment: I wouldn't say it cannot be updated, it may be difficult to do it, but surly it's not impossible.  Backup the data and write some code to go through and fix them.

Comment: Surely you can use something like this   `preg_replace('/\<img([^>]+)(?<!\/)>/', '<img\1/>', $field)` https://regex101.com/r/rNYezm/1

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix — They should not have `/` characters in them. Just because the spec requires that modern browsers ignore them, doesn't mean it's cool to waste the bytes storing and sending them.

Comment: The code in the question isn't valid HTML.

Comment: Indeed, the code you show there is an odd mixture of XML and HTML5. If it was HTML, there would be no `<?xml...` line, and the doctype line would be *exactly* `<!DOCTYPE html>`. OTOH if it was XML, it would have a correctly closed `<img />` tag. What you have there is a weird mixture that no standard tool is likely to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can use PHP's built-in DOM handling routines to parse HTML and output XML:

```
$html = <<< HEREDOC
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div>
        <figure class="table ">
            <figcaption>
                <p class="table_number"></p>
                <p class="table_title" epub:type="title"></p>
            </figcaption>
            <table class="code ">
                <tr>
                    <td width="50">
                        <img alt="" height="239" src="http://example.com/image.png" width="272">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </figure>
    </div>
</body>
HEREDOC;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
echo $dom->saveXml($dom), PHP_EOL;
```

Unfortunately, your use of an XML prolog and attempt to extend the HTML 5 Doctype as if it were an XML/SGML Doctype prevents the DOM library from successfully parsing it.

Comment: In contrast of `DOMDocument::saveHTML()` which strips self closing tags, `DOMDocument::saveXML()` places self-closing tags when missing?

Comment: @HelpNeeder — `saveHTML` saves as HTML where there is no such thing as a "self-closing tag". Just elements where the start and/or end tag are optional and/or forbidden. `saveXML` saves as XML where all tags must be explicit and a start and end tag can be combined into a self-closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

I would update the old tags with something like this,

```
$field = preg_replace('/\<img([^>]+)(?<!\/)>/', '<img\1/>', $field);
```

You can see it [here](https://regex101.com/r/rNYezm/1)

Using a negative lookbehind we can match all unclosed `img` tags, capture the "guts" in each one, and then replace it with a closed tag.

- `\<img`  literal match
- `([^>]+)` capture anything that is not a `>`
- `(?<!\/)>` negative lookbehind, match the ending `>` if not preceded by a `/`, ie. matches `>` not `/>`

So given a tag like this

it will capture `\1`, (`{}`to show spacing is captured)

```
 { alt="" height="239" src="http://example.com/image.png" width="272"}
```

Then we simply replace the `<img` and then the `>` with a `/>` and put the "guts" back in with `\1`

And our tag is now closed

```
<img alt="" height="239" src="http://example.com/image.png" width="272"/>
```

This could be expanded with another capture group and a list of tags like this:

```
$field = preg_replace('/\<(img|br)([^>]*)(?<!\/)>/', '<\1\2/>', $field);
```

And now it will match `<br>` and replace it with `<br/>` as well as the `img` tag.  All the while ignoring closed tags like this:

```
<img alt="" height="239" src="http://example.com/image2.png" width="272"/>
```

See this one [here](https://regex101.com/r/rNYezm/2)

So, it's not impossible.

I feel obligated to mention, that you should always export a backup of the table before doing any changes of this sort of scope.  That way you can be sure if something is wrong you have a safety net.

Answer (score 1):

The proper method to parse HTML, including HTML5, and then format it into XML is to use SGML, the superset of HTML and XML. You can use the `osx` program (part of the OpenSP/OpenJade package) specifically designed for this purpose. Install it via `sudo apt-get install opensp` on Ubuntu/Debian.

In SGML, you use a DTD file containing markup declarations to tell SGML which start- and end-element tags can be omitted, among other things. You can use my HTML 5.1 DTD at http://sgmljs.net/docs/w3c-html51-dtd.html for this purpose (just copy the DTD code text on that page into a file named `html51.dtd`, say). The HTML file to parse then needs to reference the .dtd file so its first line should look like

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "html51.dtd">
```

assuming `html51.dtd` is in the same directory as the file to parse. In case you wondered, SGML is where the  `DOCTYPE` declaration at the begin of many HTML documents come from, though browsers abused it for detecting HTML versions and other stuff. Anyway, your HTML must not contain two or more DOCTYPE declarations. So if it already contains a line such as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

you replace that line with the one I wrote above.

Now you just invoke

```
osx your-file.html > your-file.xml
```

(where `your-file.html` is the file you want to parse and that you've edited to begin with the proper DOCTYPE declaration) and you have a proper XML file `your-file.xml`, or will see detailed error messages otherwise.

If you want to learn more about my HTML DTD, I gave a talk on it a year ago at the XML Prague conference. The slides and the full text are linked from http://sgmljs.net/blog.html.